# How can I make it so that when I change a tagged word in tkinter, the color changes back?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I am making a text editor, and I am using Pygments to help with syntax highlighting. When I type a keyword, say `for`, it changes yellow, good. Well, when I either, type a letter after, say `fore`, `for` is still yellow, **OR** if I backspace, `fo` or `f` is yellow.

Why doesn't it change back to black/clear the color? Is there an efficient way to do this? My code, just incase needed, is as follows, there is no bug, so I am going to just include the highlighting function, even though that itself is probably unneeded.

I'll include more if needed

```
import sys #imports
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer #python syntax highlighter
from pygments import lex
major_version = sys.version_info.major
if major_version == 2: #check python version for importing tkinter
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkFileDialog
elif major_version == 3:
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog
else:
    raise RuntimeError('Unexpected python major version: %d' % major_version)

def highlight(t, previousContent):
    content = t.get("1.0", END)
    lines = content.split("\n")

    if(content != previousContent):
        t.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
        data = t.get("1.0", "end-1c")

        for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
            t.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
            t.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")

            t.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

def highlightLine(t, previousContent):
    content = t.get("1.0", END)
    lines = content.split("\n")
    currentCursorPosition = t.index(INSERT)
    currentCursorPositionSplit = currentCursorPosition.split(".")
    currentLine = currentCursorPositionSplit[0]
    currentColumn = currentCursorPositionSplit[1]

    if(content != previousContent):
        t.mark_set("range_start", str(currentLine) + ".0")
        data = t.get(str(currentLine) + ".0", str(currentLine) + "." + str(currentColumn))

        for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
            t.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
            t.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")

            t.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

def initHighlight(t):
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Constant", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Declaration", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Namespace", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Pseudo", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Reserved", foreground="#CC7A00")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Keyword.Type", foreground="#CC7A00")

    t.tag_configure("Token.Name.Class", foreground="#003D99")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Name.Exception", foreground="#003D99")
    t.tag_configure("Token.Name.Function", foreground="#003D99")

    t.tag_configure("Token.Operator.Word", foreground="#CC7A00")

    t.tag_configure("Token.Comment", foreground="#B80000")

    t.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String", foreground="#248F24")
```

This question is **NOT** asking how to remove *all* tags from the text, it's asking how do I check if a word that was tagged isn't the desirable word anymore, then get rid of the tag *on that word*. If I were to remove all tags then retag everything, it would be way too laggy.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I am not asking to remove all tags, just one or two. -- based on if it was changed from the original tag.

Comment: Hum. Are you saying when you type a word it highlights the word but when you press back space its still highlighting the shortened word instead of changing back?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it doesn't change back after being highlighting, so if `for` highlights, if i type an `e` after, making `fore`, the `for` of `fore` is still highlighted. Or if I backspace, `fo` or `f` is highlighted. Really weird

Comment: What if you monitored an event for cursor movement or typing and then have the program only check within so many spaces of the cursor or just the word to the left of the cursor using something like regex. This way you can constantly check the word that is being typed and if it fits one of the tags then it will highlight but if it does not then it will then delete the tag near the cursor if a tag exist. I would imaging the code would be moderately complex but seam possible to me.

Comment: I am continually checking, the `highlightLine` function above does that, but it for some reason doesn't reset the word when it's not highlighted. -- Unless you mean resetting the line, then checking again, I haven't thought of that.

Comment: You might be able to have the line check. So the line could be check and delete all tags on the line and then research text on that line that matches any tags. Thought this will not work for anything that is multi line.

Comment: How would I be able to check the line itself for tags? The `Text` object in tk is what contains tags, not a string.

Comment: By checking the index range of that line. You can get the index of the line and then check that line by itself by applying the index range to the search rather than the entire text box.

Comment: `for tag in text...` .. How would I get the index I want [Current line]? If I just get a string of the current line, it doesn't contain tags.

Comment: Nevermind, got it! Making an answer. Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before tagging, in the same function, I added

```
for tag in t.tag_names():
    t.tag_remove(tag, str(currentLine) + ".0", str(currentLine) + "." + str(currentColumn))
```

It checks all tags, then remove tags in the current line, then, afterwards, it will add them back, the full function goes as follows:

```
def highlightLine(t, previousContent):
    content = t.get("1.0", END)
    lines = content.split("\n")
    currentCursorPosition = t.index(INSERT)
    currentCursorPositionSplit = currentCursorPosition.split(".")
    currentLine = currentCursorPositionSplit[0]
    currentColumn = currentCursorPositionSplit[1]

    if(content != previousContent):
        t.mark_set("range_start", str(currentLine) + ".0")
        data = t.get(str(currentLine) + ".0", str(currentLine) + "." + str(currentColumn))

        for tag in t.tag_names():
            t.tag_remove(tag, str(currentLine) + ".0", str(currentLine) + "." + str(currentColumn))

        for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
            t.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
            t.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")

            t.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")
```

Works perfectly now!

Comment: Nice. I am glad you were able to work with the line.